# Getting max value on duplicate row considering join of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables

**students_tbl**

**students_results_tbl**

students_tbl

```
------------------------------------------------------
student_id | student_name | 
------------------------------------------------------
1            Mark
2            Jhon
3            Michael
4            Steven  
------------------------------------------------------
```

students_results_tbl

```
------------------------------------------------------
student_id | course_id | student_mark 
------------------------------------------------------
1            33            100
2            2             50
3            33            200  
4            10            80 
------------------------------------------------------
```

My problem , I want to select everything from results table based on specific course id with the highest mark if only the course_id is duplicated and students names from the students table based on generated students id from results table

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem, you want to *get the highest student for each course*.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    students_tbl a
        INNER JOIN students_results_tbl b
            ON a.student_id = b.student_id
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  course_ID, MAX(student_mark) max_grade
            FROM    students_results_tbl
            GROUP   BY course_ID
        ) c ON  b.course_id = c.course_id  AND
                b.student_mark = c.max_grade
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c0a5/1)

RESULT

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╗
║ STUDENT_ID ║ STUDENT_NAME ║ COURSE_ID ║ STUDENT_MARK ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╣
║          2 ║ Jhon         ║         2 ║           50 ║
║          3 ║ Michael      ║        33 ║          200 ║
║          4 ║ Steven       ║        10 ║           80 ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

**UPDATE 1**

For faster performance, add a compound `INDEX` on `course_id and student_mark`,

```
ALTER TABLE students_results_tbl INDEX (course_id, student_mark)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    students_tbl a
        INNER JOIN students_results_tbl b
            ON a.student_id = b.student_id
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  student_id,
                    course_ID, 
                    MAX(student_mark) max_grade
            FROM    students_results_tbl 
            GROUP   BY student_id, course_ID
        ) c ON  b.course_id = c.course_id  AND
                b.student_ID = c.student_id AND
                b.student_mark = c.max_grade
WHERE   b.course_ID = 33
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3371d1/6)

Comment: It works fine , but when I try to use where course_id='$Course_ID' , I get nothing .

Comment: yes this is exactly what I want . but I don't know why it doesn't work with me when add that condition

Comment: what is your original query? maybe you have done something wrong.

Comment: aha i noticed that it only returns the highest values only for duplication , but what I want is to return all marks in addition to the highest ones if there's a duplication

Comment: can you post you desired result?

Comment: is this what you want? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c0a5/4 i'm confused of this: *I want is to return all marks in addition to the highest ones if there's a duplication*

Comment: see this it should return Mark and Michael 
but it retuen Mark only
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3371d1/3

Comment: yes it's ok but please notice if I have a duplicate course , it doesn't work correctly , check this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3371d1/5

Comment: what if I try to join another table 
I have a 3rd table "academic_years" and I want to select everything like last one but with the max year order as well check this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d379f/1

Comment: can you tell what is your desired output? `:)`

Comment: I want this output http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d379f/1
but with only the max year order from academic years it means , the output will be mark and michael with year_id 2

Comment: I want everything from table b and I want year_id according to the max year_order form academic_years table

Comment: sorry I'm now confused. Can you create picture that shows how us the result looked like? I'm willing to help.

Comment: I want the result exactly like this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/449ef/1  but with (year_id) equal to 1 because it's has the order 2 in academic years table http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/78/38943540.jpg

Comment: the min give me the year_id with 1  but It doesn't matter MIN or MAX , I just want the year_id which has the highest order inside academic_years table

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this, if I'm understanding your question correctly

```
SELECT MAX(student_mark)
FROM students_results_tbl
WHERE course_id = ???
GROUP BY course_id
HAVING COUNT(course_id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will return all course_id's with the max student mark where there are more than one records in the results table

```
SELECT course_id, MAX(student_mark)
FROM students_resultstbl r
GROUP BY course_id HAVING COUNT (r.student_id) > 1
```